# Switch to another modal dialog in MFC

Tags: c++, mfc, modal-dialog

I have a modal dialog. I open another modal dialog using `DoModal`, so that there are now two dialogs, one on top of another. When I then close the top dialog by clicking okay, I get an assertion error for line 896 of mfc90ud.dll. How can I fix this?

Comment: Did you set the `owner` property of the second dialog to the first dialog?

Answer (score 0):

Hi probably you did not set parent for your child dialog

```
CMyDialog dlg(this);
```

Comment: I tried: `CDialog dlgMatched(IDD_OKAY_DIALOG,this); dlgMatched.DoModal();`, but it still crashed

Comment: @Casebash Can you add new dialog in resource editor that by right click on it add variable with name CMyDialog and try call it CMyDialog dlg(this); dlg.DoModal(); Maybe some trouble with resource fill its sometimes happend

Comment: @Casebash its my mistake, hm how can you use mfc in dll? Its strange that dialog crash